# css different paddings on different resolution

Tags: html, css, padding, resolution

How can I set padding to 0 when I have resolution 1366x768px if its higher then 768 then i want padding to be 60 on top

This is what I tried so far but it is not working (tried with min-height, max-height, etc). Any other solution for this?

```css
@media (min-height: 768px) {
    body{
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
}
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin: 5%;
}
```

so how can i remove padding when my resolution is smaller then 786px ?

Comment: change the @media query to below body class.in Css file you need to  write first general class after that specific class to override above class .

Comment: Please take a look at how css specificity works: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specified the rules in wrong order. They should be:

```css
body {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin: 5%;
}
@media (min-height: 768px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 60px;
    }
}
```

NB: it seems like you are trying to target 768px tall *screens*, the actual height used by the browser will be lesser.